# Real Time Database.in Laravel and Websockets

Tags: database, laravel, websocket

Is there any way through which we can update data on Front end when we make some changes in database in Laravel and Websockets without using Tokens/Passport.
Just simply show updated data in Real time without Timeout.

Answer (score 0):

A simple Solution for this is a websocket server in node which get the updates from laravel through redis publish. 
The websocket server subscribe for the client(front user) in the topic, you push your data through.

Here is some code to try out. (no auth, so dont use in prod!). redistopic is the topic for redis

```
var express = require('express'),
fs = require('fs'),
http = require('http'),
server = http.createServer(app),
var app = express();

/* redis + socket.io */
const redis = require('redis');
const io = require('socket.io');
server.listen(8080);
log("Server Start");

io.listen(server).on('connection', function (socket) {
const redisClient = redis.createClient();

socket.on('auth', function (data) {
    if(data.sockethash == 'noauth')
        redisClient.subscribe('redistopic')
}

// Redis Nachrichten Verabrieten und entsprechend weiterleiten
redisClient.on("message", function (channel, message) {
    if (channel == "redistopic")
        socket.emit('redistopic', message);
});

socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    redisClient.quit();
});
```

});

The javascript part

```
socket = io.connect('localhost:8080');
socket.on('connect', function (data) {
        socket.emit('auth', { sockethash: 'noauth' });
});
socket.on('redistopic', function (data) {
   var jd = JSON.parse(data); // if data is json
   console.log(jd) // else use data 
}
```

Laravel code for publish updates
need "use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;" before

```
Redis::publish('redistopic', json_encode(
        [
            'var1' => 'value1',
            'var2' => 'value2',
        ]
    ));
```

Comment: You're better off using Laravel Echo than socket.io (possibly 2-3 lines of code in total). Also, this solution doesn't talk about the backend changes required.

Comment: right. added the redis code, the [Eloquent event observers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#events) is needed too